# Handeling Error when using push(data) Angularfire2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase, angularfire2

How to handle Error when pushing data with angularFire2?

I used the following method:

```
todoLists: AngularFireList<TodoList>;

addList(data): ThenableReference {

    const item: Item = {
      name: data.task,
      state: false,
      description: 'No description'
    };
    const todoList: TodoList = {
      id: '',
      name: data.name,
      items: [item]
    };
    this.todoLists.push(todoList).then(_ => this.presentToast('List succesfuly added'))
                               .catch(err => _ => this.presentToast('Something wrong happened'));
  }
```

The problem here is that the push method of `AngularFire` returns an `ThenableReference` so the catch method doesn't exist in that interface.

Here's the message from the editor (vscode)

> property catch doesn't exist on type promiseLike<>
>   There must another way to handle errors.

Comment: Related Question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48656056/property-catch-does-not-exist-on-type-promiselikevoid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, and I found I could create the thenable reference with the push() method, then use set which returns an error on .catch.

See more [here in the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#set).

```
todoLists: AngularFireList<TodoList>;

addList(data): void {
  const item: Item = {
    name: data.task,
    state: false,
    description: 'No description'
  };
  const todoList: TodoList = {
    id: '',
    name: data.name,
    items: [item]
  };

  // .push() also creates a new unique key, which can be accessed with ref.key
  let ref: Reference = this.todoLists.push(); 
  ref.set(todoList)
    .then( () => this.presentToast('List succesfuly added'))
    .catch(err => this.presentToast('Something wrong happened: ' + err));
}
```